# error creating Application AutoScaling Target: ValidationException: Unsupported service namespace, resource type or scalable dimension

Tags: module, terraform, amazon-ecs, autoscaling, aws-fargate

I'm trying to enable ECS autoscaling for some Fargate services and run into the error in the title:

`error creating Application AutoScaling Target: ValidationException: Unsupported service namespace, resource type or scalable dimension`

The error happens on line 4 here:

```
resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "autoscaling" {
  max_capacity = var.max_capacity
  min_capacity = 1
  resource_id  = var.resource_id
  //  <snip... a bunch of other vars not relevant to question>
```

I call the custom autoscaling module like so:

```
module "myservice_autoscaling" {
  source = "../autoscaling"
  resource_id = aws_ecs_service.myservice_worker.id
  //  <snip... a bunch of other vars not relevant to question>
```

My service is a normal ECS service block starting with:

`resource "aws_ecs_service" "myservice_worker" {`

After poking around online, I thought maybe I should construct the "service/clusterName/serviceName" sort of "manually", like so:

`resource_id = "service/${var.cluster_name}/${aws_ecs_service.myservice_worker.name}"`

But that leads to a different error:

`The argument "cluster_name" is required, but no definition was found.`

I created `cluster_name` in my calling module (i.e. myservice ECS stuff that calls my new autoscaling module) variables.tf. And I have `cluster_name` in the `outputs.tf` of our cluster module where we're setting up the ECS cluster. I must be missing some linking still.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**Edit: here's the solution that got it working for me**

1. Yes, you do need to construct the resource_id in the form of `"service/yourClusterName/yourServiceName"`. Mine ended up looking like: `"service/${var.cluster_name}/${aws_ecs_service.myservice_worker.name}"`
2. You need to make sure you have access to the cluster name and service name variables. In my case, though I had the variable defined in my ECS service's `variables.tf`, and I added it my cluster module's `outputs.tf`, I was failing to pass down from the root module to the service module. This fixed that:

```
module "myservice" {
  source = "./modules/myservice"
  cluster_name = module.cluster.cluster_name // the line I added
```

(the preceding snippet goes in the `main.tf` of your root module (a level above your service module)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track constructing the `"service/${var.cluster_name}/${aws_ecs_service.myservice_worker.name}"` string. It looks like you simply aren't referencing the cluster name correctly.

> And I have cluster_name in the outputs.tf of our cluster module

So you need to reference that module output, instead of referencing a not-existent variable:

```
"service/${module.my_cluster_module.cluster_name}/${aws_ecs_service.myservice_worker.name}"
```

Change "my_cluster_module" to whatever name you gave the module that is creating your ECS cluster.

Comment: Thank you, Mark! I ended up doing it a little bit differently; however, your comment was invaluable in getting me on the right track. I'll update the body of the question above with an edit showing what I ended up doing.